# Display different arrays in collectionView after click on different rows in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

In my **viewController** i have **tableView** and **collectionView**.

And i try to **display** **different arrays** in **collectionView** when i click on **different rows** in **tableView**.

So when i click on **firstRow** in **tableView**, i want to display **firstArray** in **collectionView**, when i click on **secondRow** in **tableView**, i want to display **secondArray** in **collectionView** and when i click on **thirdRow** in **tableView**, i want to display **thirdArray** in **collectionView**.

How can i do this?

My test code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var tableArray: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    var secondArray: [String] = ["One", "Two"]
    var thirdArray: [String] = ["Three", "Four"]
    var fourthArray: [String] = ["Five", "Six"]

    // TABLEVIEW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        cell.tableLabel.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }

    // COLLECTIONVIEW
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return secondArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        cell.collectionLabel.text = secondArray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}

class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableLabel: UILabel!
}

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I understand what need to use condition `if`, but how to use correct it?

Comment: I'd suggest to use a `var collectionArray`that would be used for your `UICollectionView`. In `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`: `if indexPath.row == 0 { collectionArray = secondArray} else if indexPath.row == 1 { collectionArray = thirdArray}... collectionView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add your arrays inside a dictionary (`collectionData`) using the index as key, in this way their lookup is totally dynamic and you don't need any `if then else`, so your code might be:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var tableArray: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]

    // you may want to feed the dictionary directly with the arrays (feel free to remove them)
    var collectionData: [Int: [String]] = [:] 
    var secondArray: [String] = ["One", "Two"]
    var thirdArray: [String] = ["Three", "Four"]
    var fourthArray: [String] = ["Five", "Six"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionData[0] = secondArray
        self.collectionData[1] = thirdArray
        self.collectionData[2] = fourthArray
    }

    func getCurrentArray() -> [String]? {
        let currentRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row ?? 0
        let array = self.collectionData[currentRow]
        return array
    }

    // TABLEVIEW
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
        cell.tableLabel.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    // COLLECTIONVIEW
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.getCurrentArray()?.count ?? 0
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
        cell.collectionLabel.text = self.getCurrentArray()?[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath)
    }
}

class TableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableLabel: UILabel!
}

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and use it. And with the help of key you can easily fetch the different data from different table view cell.